# Disable shortcuts in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, keyboard-shortcuts

Is their a way to disable default keyboard shortcuts in Access 2013's forms? Like disabling `ctrl+s = save record`?

Comment: I think it's under File >> Options >> Current Database >> Use Access Special Keys.

Comment: This is working to disable some shortcuts like accessing to the navigation panel, etc. But my main issue is to disable the "save record" shortcut (cmd+s) which is not disabled by this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only method I found to disable ctrl+p was with an AutoKeys macro. Perhaps the same is true for cmd+s.

[image]

However, not seeing cmd+ referenced in https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Run-an-Access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-0D267570-D3DA-46EB-9BFB-A3C81AF676BE

Did you perhaps mean ctrl+s?

Comment: Yeah I meant ctrl+s. And it's working fine, thank you :) Just one question, do you know if I can make this macro applicable for only one form or it must act for the entire project?

Comment: Perhaps with one of the form Key events. The macro could not be named AutoKeys. Or maybe VBA instead. So no, I really do not know.