# Capture & Release Ctrl+c (For the whole Database)

Tags: vba, ms-access, copy

How do you disable ctrl+c for certain users? (This should be done for the whole database and not just a single form or report)

This is what I got so far:

[image]

```
Public Function ctrlC()
    'prevent unauthorised users from copying data using the ctrl + c shortcut
    If ActiveUserLevel < 2 Then
        'disalbe ctrl + c
        MsgBox "crtl c disabled"
    Else
        'allow user to use ctrl + c
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy  'Error: "The cmd or action copy isn't available right now"
    End If
End Function
```

PS: I realize you could use the KEY DOWN event in a form, but I'm looking for a more efficient solution (I don't want to call the key down method on 100 different forms and possibly missing some of them...)

*UPDATE*

As inspired by Sion.D.P's comment another idea was to build 2 macros. One that disable ctrl+c and another that is blank, then rename them depending on the userAccessLevel with this function:

```
Public Sub enableUserShortcuts(val As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next:
    'swap macro names to enable/disable user shortcut keys

    If val = False Then
        'disable user shorcuts
        DoCmd.RunMacro "AutoKeys_DisableUserShortcuts"  'test if macro needs to be loaded
        If err.number = 0 Then
            DoCmd.Rename "AutoKeys_Blank", acMacro, "AutoKeys"  'save old macro
            DoCmd.Rename "AutoKeys", acMacro, "AutoKeys_DisableUserShortcuts"   'load macro
        End If

    Else
        'enable user shorcuts
        DoCmd.RunMacro "AutoKeys_Blank"  'test if macro needs to be loaded
        If err.number = 0 Then
            DoCmd.Rename "AutoKeys_DisableUserShortcuts", acMacro, "AutoKeys"   'save old macro
            DoCmd.Rename "AutoKeys", acMacro, "AutoKeys_Blank"  'load macro
        End If

    End If

    err.number = 0
    DoCmd.RunMacro "AutoKeys"
End Sub
```

Or to import xml macro files with a function(https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104045/5148062):

```
Public Sub enableUserShortcuts(val As Boolean)
    'swap macro names to enable/disable user shortcut keys
    If val = False Then
        'disable user shorcuts
        LoadFromText acMacro, "AutoKeys", "C:\New folder\AutoKeys_DisableUserShortcuts.xml"
    Else
        'enable user shorcuts
        LoadFromText acMacro, "AutoKeys", "C:\New folder\AutoKeys_Blank.xml"
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem with both of the last 2 'solutions' are that the database doesn't seem to update once the above rename/import is done. You got to close the whole db and open it up again for it to work. If I don't close & reopen I get the following error: "YourDbName cant find the macro ^c in the macro group autokeys"

Comment: You want to display data to the user but if he wants to use it, he has to type it manually? If I where a user, I would curse the programmer and try to use a solution as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21909259/7599798 - just my 2 cents

Comment: ^^ just what I was about to write - this would be super annoying to your users. And the old-timers will just use Ctrl+Insert and Shift+Insert instead ([link](https://superuser.com/a/428406/544673)) or find another way.

Comment: There is a way to do it In Excel. It is frequently used in Excel for 'closed' workbooks.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945148/disable-shortcuts-in-access-2013)

Comment: @FunThomas Captain's orders,,, The user/s to be blocked are raw or temporary employees, once they sign contract they will have a higher access level. We aim to protect the data even if it cause discomfort to a minority of the users

Comment: @Sion.D.P yes thanks. The image of the macro I pasted, capture the ctrl+c event. But I'm struggling to 'release' it (the copy should proceed if the user got a high enough accessLevel)

Comment: @andre I have updated the code thx. Will have to block ctrl+insert as well...

Comment: @Rhdr you shuld be able to enable / disable macros after login to the app acording to user priviladges

Comment: Well, one could and should likely  be distributing a compiled version of the application. That way ctrl-c, or in fact ANY un-handled error will NEVER re-set any of your VBA variables. This results in a FAR more reliable application since your VBA vars (local and global) will NEVER be re-set. Users also can't view your code, and ctrl-c does not work. For the "vast" majority of those developing applications, they do choose to distribute a compiled version of their software - and that includes access developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the macro switching procedure as described in the updated part of the question resulted in the db having to be restarted. Here is a batch script that wait a while for the db to close then reopens it after login:

```
Private Sub createDBBatchScript()
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(Environ("temp") & "\vba.cmd", True, False)
    Fileout.Write "@echo off " & vbNewLine & _
                    "Rem used within vba to reopen db, once vba execute this script, " & vbNewLine & _
                    "Rem the script waits for a short while then if the db is closed it reopens it " & vbNewLine & _
                    "Rem if reopend create temp txt file else delete any temp txt files " & vbNewLine & _
                    vbNewLine & _
                    "set /a counter=0 " & vbNewLine & _
                    vbNewLine & _
                    ": runAgain " & vbNewLine & _
                    "set /a counter+=1 " & vbNewLine & _
                    "Rem echo %counter% " & vbNewLine & _
                    vbNewLine & _
                    "if %counter% leq 5000 ( " & vbNewLine & _
                    "    if not exist " & Application.CurrentProject.path & "\DB_FE.laccdb ( " & vbNewLine & _
                    "        Rem echo does not exists " & vbNewLine & _
                    "        echo 1 > %temp%\psReopened.txt " & vbNewLine & _
                    "        Start " & Application.CurrentProject.path & "\DB_FE.accde " & vbNewLine & _
                    "    ) else ( " & vbNewLine & _
                    "        Rem echo still exist " & vbNewLine & _
                    "        goto runAgain) " & vbNewLine & _
                    ") else ( " & vbNewLine & _
                    "    del %temp%\dbReopened.txt " & vbNewLine & _
                    ") " & vbNewLine & _
                    vbNewLine & _
                    "Rem pause "

    Fileout.Close
    Set Fileout = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also I added an AutoExec macro & funciton to cleanup any temp leftover files created by the bacth script & help smooth over the login proccess

[image]

```
Public Function startup()
'if db is reopend by bacth script go straight to switchboard else login screen
    If Not Dir(Environ("temp") & "\vba.cmd") = "" Then
        Kill Environ("temp") & "\vba.cmd"

        If Dir(Environ("temp") & "\psReopened.txt") = "" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Login Form"
        Else
            Kill Environ("temp") & "\psReopened.txt"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "SwitchMain"
        End If
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Login Form"
    End If
End Function
```

A benefit of generating everything in vba is that there is no left over files floating around, before or after running the scripts